# I'm encountering a connection issue (ConnectionResetError) while trying to make multiple requests to an API

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

Problem Description:
I'm encountering a connection issue while trying to make multiple requests to an API. Initially, I was making approximately 2000 requests, but I received a `ConnectionResetError`. However, when I reduced the number of requests to about 40, it worked fine. I'm unsure why this discrepancy is occurring.

Code Snippet:

```
print(6)
import time
import json
import requests
import pandas as pd

start_time = time.time()

path = 'C:/Users/Mubaraq/Downloads/airport_codes.xlsx'
airport_codes = pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl')
airport_codes.sort_values(by='Code', ascending=True, inplace=True)
codes = airport_codes['Code'].tolist()
new_codes = ['K' + i for i in codes]
new_codes_ = new_codes[100:150]

counter = list(range(len(new_codes)))
Total_departures = pd.DataFrame()
Total_arrival = pd.DataFrame()
Departures = []
Arrivals = []

for i, j in zip(new_codes, counter):
    def file_path_():
        url = f'https://api.aviationapi.com/v1/vatsim/pilots?apt={i}'
        response = requests.get(url)
        if j % 40 == 0:
            time.sleep(42)
        df_departures = pd.DataFrame()
        df_arrivals = pd.DataFrame()
        if response.status_code == 200:
            data = response.json()
            try:
                df_departures = pd.DataFrame(data[i]['Departures'])
                df_arrivals = pd.DataFrame(data[i]['Arrivals'])
            except KeyError:
                pass
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch data. Status code: {response.status_code}")
        return df_departures, df_arrivals

    A, B = file_path_()
    Total_departures = pd.concat([Total_departures, A], ignore_index=True)
    Total_arrival = pd.concat([Total_arrival, B], ignore_index=True)

Total_departures.to_csv('Total Departures.csv', index=False)
Total_arrival.to_csv('Total Arrival.csv', index=False)

end_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = end_time - start_time
print("Elapsed time:", elapsed_time, "seconds")
```

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mubaraq\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\Mubaraq\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
```

...
ConnectionResetError:

```
[WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
```

Specific Questions and Note:
Why am I receiving a `ConnectionResetError` when making a large number of requests, but not when making fewer requests?
How can I troubleshoot and resolve this connection issue?
Is there a better way to structure my code to handle a large number of API requests without encountering this error?
I would also appreciate if you run this code for better understanding